# UK TV Licensing changes 2016 - which Law or Legislation changed to facilitate this?

Tags: copyright, united-kingdom

Various sources such as the [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-37226030) and [MoneySavingExpert](http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/utilities/tv-licence) talk about the law changing with regards to TV licensing, specifically stating that UK Residents now require a TV License to watch catch-up (rather than Live) content on the BBC iPlayer, from Sept 1, 2016

However, I can't find any legislation or legal ruling that changes, amends, or supersedes the relevant act (Communications Act 2003 Part 4)

Legally speaking, what changed to require a TV License in order to watch Catch UP TV on the BBC iPlayer?

Comment: There is probably not a law change required - just a decision that watching catch up TV is just a different way of watching TV, similar to recording it on a video recorder and watching later.

Comment: In this case though I've repeatedly seen the claim that "the law has changed" - and the BBC can't just change their own personal interpretation of the law, so something must have changed in the legal interpretation... I just can't work out what

Answer (score 2):

The changes in legislation for TV licensing which affects use of BBC iPlayer are covered in:

1. [The Audiovisual Media Services Regulations 2009](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2009/2979/made) (particularly sections 368A & 368R) which provides legislation defining "on-demand programme services" (e.g. BBC iPlayer) and their regulation by OFCOM, and
2. [The Communications (Television Licensing) (Amendment) Regulations 2016](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2016/704/made) (Section 9) which defines circumstances in which a TV licence is required for use of BBC iPlayer. These are the new rules that came into force on 1 Sep 2016.

Hope that this helps.